# Creating a dynamic seach using MvvM and WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am fairly new to mvvm and WPF so I am looking for some pointers to achieve the following.

I would like to create a search section in my app that builds up the search options based on whatever the users selects as their criteria.

So for example the first combo box of the search offers the top level of choices:

Date of Message

Gateway

Direction

Etc..
......

The second section is my operator

So, for example if Date of Message is selected then the user is offered another combo box of choices

Is Between

Last Week

Last Month

Etc..

The last section of the search is based on the operator above, so if Is Between is selected the form displays two Date Pickers from and to. If on the other hand Last Week is selected then nothing is displayed as the search can directly call my SetActionLogsForLastWeek() method once I click my search button.

If the user selects Gateway from the initial list then another combo box is build with a list of choices based on gateways.

I am looking for a tutorial or previous post that points me in the right direction on achieving my goal of building WPF elements based on selection choices from other elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather extensive question, and as such there is no definitive answer. I will describe how I would handle this problem. Keep in mind that this might not be the best solution out there.

In order to render the controls which depend on the first combo box use data templates and distinct view models. In the resource section of your main view, or an external resource if you have defined one, write something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:YourViewModel}"> <vw:YourView /> </DataTemplate>
```

You will have to import the namespaces containing your viewmodels and views (vm: and vw: here). Using content-controls you can render views depending on their viewmodels:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"></ContentControl>
```

In your code behind, you will have to have a ViewModel which you can bind to. Depending on the selection of the first combo box, you can now swap out the ViewModel in the code behind in order to render the dependent combo boxes - or nothing at all!

In order to illustrate, let me provide some sample code. Lets start with you main view model. Thats the one containing the collection the first combo box binds to (e.g. the strings "Date of Message","Gateway"...)

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    public IObservableCollection comboBoxItems;
    public BaseViewModel ControlViewModel {get; set;}
    private String selectedItem;
    public String SelectedItem {
        get {
            return selectedItem;
        }
        set {
            selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            ChangeControls();
        }
    }

    private void ChangeControls(){
       switch(selectedItem):
           //swap out the control view model here e.g.
           controlViewModel = new GateWayControlViewModel();
    }

}
```

Btw, BaseViewModel is an abstract class which all view models inherit from. It implements INotifyPropertyChanged. 
In your main view it is enough to have content control binding to the control view model, as well as the first combo box:

In your resources.xaml you define the data template, as discussed before.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vw:GatewayControlViewModel}"> <vw:GatewayView /> </DataTemplate>
```

This will render the GateWayView if the ViewModel, which the ContentControl in the main view is bound to is equal to GateWayControlViewModel. Finally, your GatewayView could look like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Gateways}" 
        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedGateway}" />
```

Obviously, you will have to make sure your GatewayControlViewModel actually contains the items and properties mentioned in the view. It will also need to derive from BaseViewModel.

I hope this gives you some ideas. Additionally, you might find [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) useful (as it contains some very useful tips on how to approach MVVM).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement Search in Collections for example in as in Combobox or Grid you should read a bit about ICollectionView. The ICollectionView will allow you to filter collection based on your search criteria. In your example you can also do this by handling selection changed events at the viewmodel and create method to update your data based on selected inputs.